# A set valued intermediate value theorem.

Tags: analysis, multivalued-functions

Does anyone know of an intermediate value theorem for set valued maps which are upper semicontinuous? Specifically, I'm looking for a theorem which says that, for example, if we are in $R^3$ and we look at two points and one maps to a set in the first quadrant and the other to a set in the eighth quadrant then on a line between them there either exist a finite amount of points mapping to the quadrants that a path from the first quadrant to the eighth quadrant must go through or there exists a point (on the line) which maps to the origin. Thanks.

Comment: Mmm, there is no uniquely defined path between quadrants - such a path can be as convoluted as we want. And, besides, are we talking about vector-valued or set-valued functions? Because even for vector-valued functions the IVT does not really exist , and I believe for set-valued function the situation is even worse.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy maybe the way I wrote the question is a little confusing, I'm not looking for an intermediate value theorem exactly, rather I'm asking whether there is a way to prove that the set of sets mapped to by the points on the line (between the two points) is connected (or path connected). (The same way the intermediate value theorem basically says that  a continuous function maps a line to a path, in other words it keeps it connected.)

Comment: Topologically speaking, the continuous image of a path-connected set is path-connected. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AJY Not exactly, we don't have here the continuous image of a path-connected set, rather a set valued maps which is upper semicontinuous. This map takes a point to a set. So, for example, it might take a line in $R^n$ to a set in $R^n$, and I want to prove that the image is connected, given that the line is connected. But remember, we are not dealing with a continuous point to point function, but rather with a set valued maps which is upper semicontinuous. Thanks for your help.